# Hibernate cannot run this hql query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have this query

```
select faktur.* from
(select a.no_do, a.no_faktur, b.dlr_nama, a.crea_date from honda_h100_fakdos a, honda_h000_dealers b where a.kd_dlr=b.kd_dlr and a.status<>'X' and a.do_tahun>='2012') faktur
```

it's running without problem on my SQL manager, but i always getting  this error message when I convert this SQL to HQL.

```
"expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1"
```

below is my HQL

```
select f.* (select a.noDo, a.noFaktur, a.creaDate from HondaH100Fakdos a where a.status <> 'X' and a.doTahun >= '2012' and a.doBulan = '02')  f
```

I am still a beginner in Hibernate and Java.

Can somebody explain why Hibernate cannot translate this query to HQL?

Comment: if you are using Hibernate than use criteria, projection and all this hibernate objects instead of HQL, hibernate query create your sql query Optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a `FROM` after `SELECT`:

```
select f.* from (select a.noDo, a.noFaktur, a.creaDate 
from HondaH100Fakdos a 
where a.status <> 'X' and a.doTahun >= '2012' and a.doBulan = '02') f
```

In any case, this subselect is useless here. This will get you the same result:

```
select a.noDo, a.noFaktur, a.creaDate 
from HondaH100Fakdos a 
where a.status <> 'X' and a.doTahun >= '2012' and a.doBulan = '02'
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

db entity :

```
public class User{

int id;

String name;

// setter and getter
}
```

```
db table name : tn_user
       column : tn_id,tn_name

hql : "from User where id=? and name=?" 

? is parameter
```